# Jump to the next function by pressing Ctrl-C

Tags: bash, function

Assume that there are some functions which they do different jobs. I want to be able to press Ctrl-C to jump to the next function instead of canceling all the script at once.

I tried `trap ctrl_c INT` but it didn't work. FYI, I use curl in some of the functions.

How can I do it?

```
function first {
    # do the first job
}

function second {
    # do the second job
}

function third {
    # do the third job
}

first  &&
second &&
third  &&
rm *.del
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hooking Ctrl+C to `return 0` seems to work fine. Like:

```
# define first, second, and third here
trap 'return 0' INT
first  &&
second &&
third  &&
trap - INT &&
rm *.del
```